# Blockchain doesn´t conect to the server and miner

Tags: python, flask, server, blockchain

I have coded a simple blockchain. If I run the system, I have following problems:

1. t: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.

- Debug mode: on
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 120-407-209
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  Actually it should run on 8000 pod

```
import datetime
import json

import requests
from flask import render_template, redirect, request

from app import app

CONNECTED_NODE_ADDRESS = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

posts = []
```

So when I click on the link with the 5000, it comes following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /chain (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F9D1922880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte'))>

I run everything on the virtual environment flask (powershell).

I am pretty new in python and blockchain, so maybe it might be just a simple mistake.

Thank you for your help in advance. Kate

Comment: You can check that: https://github.com/satwikkansal/python_blockchain_app/issues/32

Comment: Thank you so much @Ta-seenJunaid for the link. I followed exactly the instructions on that page. I could solve the problem with the request connection error. But still I have one issue, it´s actually also kind of explained in the link but I don´t get it right...I worked the whole day on it... So If I run the node_server.py and the run_app_py the App/website opens on Port 8000 (http://127.0.0.1:8000/). I can enter everything but when I click Post, i get an error on my terminal and then if I click "Request to mine" it leads me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/mine, but it apperas: Not found. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I saw my mistake.
For me it wasn´t clear that I have to run the run_app.py on CMD and the node_server.py on the vs code.
So now it works...